# I have unknown BotManQuestion class from botman article

Tags: laravel, botman

In laravel 9 app I follow https://christoph-rumpel.com/2018/05/how-i-built-the-laravelquiz-chatbot-with-botman-and-laravel docs
to add botman. These articles has 3 using of BotManQuestion class  and I have an error :

```
Class "App\Library\BotManQuestion" not found
```

BotManQuestion - does not look like custom or model class and I did not find it it the project or in this https://botman.io/2.0/welcome docs.
There is aloso unknown BotManAnswer class used in this article.

Any ideas what kind of class can it be ?

I installed botman with commands :

```
composer require botman/botman

composer require botman/driver-web
```

so I have "botman/botman": "^2.7" and     "botman/driver-web": "^1.5"...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding declarations :

```
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer as BotManAnswer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question as BotManQuestion;
```

salvedthis error...